# Child module is unable to install dependencies (global install) - Relative path issue?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, npm-scripts

I have an npm package with a structure like this:

```
./
  ./backend
    ./package.json
  package.json
```

So basically two npm modules in the same folder, one being a child of the other, file structure wise.

The way I install is, is that I put a post-install script in the parent package.json:

```
"postinstall": "cd backend && npm install && cd .."
```

What happens ONLY if I install it globally: It first prints some warnings that basically the packages weren't installed. Like this:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/lib/node_modules/inschpektor/backend/node_modules/trim-newlines/package.json'
```

Those appear for all dependencies in `./backend/package.json`.

I already run the installation with the `--unsafe-perm` flag:

`npm install -g inschpektor --unsafe-perm` which installs the parent package.json, that contains the postinstall script.

The final log error message I get is this one:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/inschpektor/backend/node_modules/ansi-regex/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/lib/node_modules/inschpektor/backend/node_modules/ansi-regex/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/codepleb/.npm/_logs/2019-01-02T01_52_46_911Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 254
npm ERR! inschpektor@0.9.1 postinstall: `cd backend && npm install && cd ..`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the inschpektor@0.9.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/codepleb/.npm/_logs/2019-01-02T01_52_47_511Z-debug.log
```

What am I doing wrong? Or do you maybe see flaws in the way I'm setting things up?

Here is the link to get git repo, if you would like to further analyze it: https://github.com/codepleb/inschpektor

Comment: From what I can tell, running `npm install` on the project root of your app works without a problem, and the `backend` directory doesn't even contain a `package.json` file. Is this still relevant?

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz I moved everthing in the parent node_modules folder instead of having 2 npm projects in one. Now, all the files of the "submodule" are linking to the dependencies of the main node_modules. Not sure which is the better approach. If you would find a better solution, feel free to post. This was basically the state of when I was asking this question (git hash): a907bf8dd845d63a3fc1b30dea27bc2641936639

Comment: `npm install` seems to work fine for me on the revision you mentioned. Can you mention the exact commands used to reproduce?

Comment: Why won't you make `backend` a separate package, so it could be included into your main package as a dependency?

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz You need to globally install it. The problem was on linux for me. Not all the time, or it only worked initially. I can't quantify it tbh.